# Go fmt producing inconsistently formatted results for math expressions

Tags: go, gofmt

My understanding is that go fmt is supposed to produce code that is readable and consistently formatted. However I'm not finding this to be the case.

I typed in the commented code and go fmt returned the uncommented code. Why did it collapse `0.5*(y3-y0)`, but not `0.5 * (y2 - y0)` ? How is that consistent? And, IMO, the return line with nearly every space collapsed out is a readability disaster.

Is the inconsistency a bug?
Is there a way to get go fmt to leave some lines (like the return line) alone?

```
func cubicInterpolate(x, y0, y1, y2, y3 float64) float64 {
    // 4-point, 3rd-order Hermite (x-form)
    // c0 := y1
    // c1 := 0.5 * (y2 - y0)
    // c2 := y0 - 2.5 * y1 + 2. * y2 - 0.5 * y3
    // c3 := 1.5 * (y1 - y2) + 0.5 * (y3 - y0)
    //
    // return ((c3 * x + c2) * x + c1) * x + c0

    c0 := y1
    c1 := 0.5 * (y2 - y0)
    c2 := y0 - 2.5*y1 + 2.*y2 - 0.5*y3
    c3 := 1.5*(y1-y2) + 0.5*(y3-y0)

    return ((c3*x+c2)*x+c1)*x + c0
}
```

Comment: Gofmt's style is no one's favorite, yet gofmt is everyone's favorite.

Comment: get used to it. https://go-proverbs.github.io/

Comment: I have a similar problem where gofmt is changing indentation of a structured comment that's consumed by `swagger` from spaces to tabs, resulting in an obscure swagger error: `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type spec.SecuritySchemeProps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the [go source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/printer/nodes.go#L660); the aim is to make operator precedence clear. For example in your example `y0 - 2.5*y1 + 2.*y2 - 0.5*y3` the multiplications will be performed before the subtractions and the format chosen makes this clear at a glance.

In answer to your question; this is not a bug; indeed [quite a bit of effort](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1206) was put into the formatting. You cannot exclude a line from formatting; this is by design, as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq), the aim is to enforce layont rules:

> gofmt is a pretty-printer whose purpose is to enforce layout rules; it
>   replaces the usual compendium of do's and don'ts that allows
>   interpretation.

Below is a formatted extract from [go/printer/nodes.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/printer/nodes.go#L660) that details the formatting rules:

> Format the binary expression: decide the cutoff and then format. Let's
>   call depth == 1 Normal mode, and depth > 1 Compact mode. (Algorithm
>   suggestion by Russ Cox.)
>
> The precedences are: 
>       `5             *  /  %  <<  >>  &  &^
>       4             +  -  |  ^
>       3             ==  !=  <  <=  >  >=
>       2             &&
>       1             ||`
>
> The only decision is whether there will be spaces around levels 4 and
>   5. There are never spaces at level 6 (unary), and always spaces at levels 3 and below.
>
> To choose the cutoff, look at the whole expression but excluding
>   primary expressions (function calls, parenthesized exprs), and apply
>   these rules:
>
> 1. If there is a binary operator with a right side unary operand that would clash without a space, the cutoff must be (in order):
>
> ```
>    /* 6   
>    && 6   
>    &^ 6   
>    ++ 5   
>    -- 5
> ```
>
> (Comparison operators always have spaces around them.)
>
> 2. If there is a mix of level 5 and level 4 operators, then the cutoff is 5 (use spaces to distinguish precedence) in Normal mode and 4
>      (never use spaces) in Compact mode.
> 3. If there are no level 4 operators or no level 5 operators, then the cutoff is 6 (always use spaces) in Normal mode and 4 (never use
>      spaces) in Compact mode.

Comment: I didn't have a problem with ```y0 - 2.5*y1 + 2.*y2 - 0.5*y3```. It is that ```0.5 * (y2 - y0)``` and ```0.5*(y3-y0)``` are formatted differently from each other despite being the same, and that there is nothing clear at a glance in this: ```((c3*x+c2)*x+c1)*x + c0```.

Comment: @asynth: the `0.5 * (y2 - y0)` has spaces in it because it is the entire expression. The `0.5*(y3-y0)` has no spaces because it's *not* the entire expression: it is the RHS of a sum. That's really all there is to it. (BTW I agree with you that the `return` layout is particularly terrible, but I don't get to choose here.)